# Mapping Exception in hibernate while using @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the Mapping Exception in hibernate while using `@ElementCollection`

The error goes away when I don't use `@ElementCollection`, I have gone through almost all the questions on this topic here but none of them solve my problem

Below is the Entity class

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    String name;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    String address;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name="HOBBIES",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID"))
    @Column(name="HOBBIES")
    List<String> hobbies;

    @Column(name="INTEREST")
    String interest;
```

Below is the relevant log message

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(HOBBIES)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1099)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1284)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 82 more
```

Since I couldn't pinpoint the jpa version from the library I am sharing my `pom.xml`.

Below is my current `pom.xml` for `hibernate`

```
        <!-- Hibernate resources -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have added below in my last try

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have changed `hibernate-entitymanager` version from `3.6.7.Final` to `5.1.0.Final`, both not working.

Comment: which jpa / hibernate version are you using? and share the import lib of ElementCollection

Comment: @KhalilM I have updated the question

Comment: I ran your code on my local machine and its working fine! I am using `hibernate-core: 5.0.11`, `hibernate-entitymanager: 5.0.11` and `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` v `1.1.0 Final`.

Comment: I was wondering what is the use of other dependencies, in my standalone project which I just made with just 2 dependencies which you have mentioned above, it is working fine. It's just that it is not working in the spring project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there was something wrong with hibernate dependencies when I was using it with Spring 3. After some more findings, I came up with below dependencies and everything was working as expected.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```